# Refreshing FullCalendar upon saving events with Angular Resource $save

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, factory

I'm building a calendar inspired by this example http://plnkr.co/edit/pIDltQRV6TQGD4KQYnj7?p=preview and adding $save to add new events using RESTful server connection.

I'm trying to find a way to make the calendar show the new events when they are $saved without manually refreshing the browser.

My attempt to get this to work was to add (or remove) the event data to the event array (gDataService.events). Although it does change the content of the array, the change is not shown in the calendar. (e.g., if I change the date of the event, the event won't move to the new date.)

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

HTML

```
 <div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" class="span8 calendar" ng-model="eventSources"></div>
```

Controller1 ... This saves new event.

```
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $scope.entry = new calFactory();
        $scope.entry.data = data
        $scope.entry.$save( function(){
        // data saved. do something here.
            toaster.pop('success','Message','Update successfully completed.');
        });

    };
```

Controller2 ... Main controller that defines eventSource

```
myApp.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope,$compile,uiCalendarConfig, calFactory,eventFactory, gDataService) {

gDataService.events = function(start, end, callback) {
    var d = new Date(start);
    var events;

    events = calFactory.query({
      start: start,
      end: end
    });

    events.$promise.then(function(value){
        gDataService.events = events;
      //have to call the callback as well to keep the calendar happy
        callback(gDataService.events);
        $scope.statusTxt = $scope.statusTxt  + " ... Event loading completed at " + moment(new Date()).format("HH:mm:ss");
        }
    );
};
/* event sources array*/
$scope.eventSources = [gDataService.events];  /*, $scope.eventSource, $scope.eventsF*/
})
```

Factory

```
myApp.factory("calFactory",['$resource','$filter', function($resource, $filter) {

    return $resource("/griddata/", {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET'
        },
        save: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
            transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
                data = angular.toJson(data); 
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return $.param(data.data);
            }
        }
    });
```

}]);

gDataService ... This stores event data and make it available to other parts of the program

```
myApp.factory("gDataService", function ($rootScope, calFactory) {
var service = {};
service.events = [];

service.addData = function(object, no_broadcast) {

    this.events.push({
        __id: object.task_id, title: object.task, start: object.duedates,
        backgroundColor: bColor, textColor: bTextColor, borderColor: bColor
    });

    if (!no_broadcast) {$rootScope.$broadcast("gDataUpdated")};
};

service.removeData = function(task_id, no_broadcast) {

    var arr_index = _.findIndex(this.events, {'__id': task_id});

    this.events.splice(arr_index, 1);

    if (!no_broadcast) {$rootScope.$broadcast("gDataUpdated")};
};
return service;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from chris-rock https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar/issues/200.

Changed scope.init in calendar.js like this:

```
scope.init = function(){
  calendar.fullCalendar(options);
  window.calendar = calendar;  /// This is the key
};
```

Now I can add or remove events dynamically using window.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents' or 'renderEvent')!!

Here is how I changed my code.

gDataService

```
 service.addData = function(object, no_broadcast) {
    //add additional project
    this.added_event = {
        __id: object.task_id, title: object.task, start: object.duedates,
        backgroundColor: bColor, textColor: bTextColor, borderColor: bColor
    }; 
    this.events.push(this.added_event);

    if (!no_broadcast) {$rootScope.$broadcast("gDataUpdated")};
};

service.removeData = function(_id, no_broadcast) {
    var arr_index = _.findIndex(this.events, {'_id': _id});
    this.delete_id = _id;
    this.events.splice(arr_index, 1);

    if (!no_broadcast) {$rootScope.$broadcast("gDataUpdated")};
};
return service;
```

Controller

```
$scope.$on('gDataUpdated', function(){
    if (gDataService.delete_id) {
        window.calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents',gDataService.delete_id); // This removes this event from the calendar
        gDataService.delete_id = null;
    };
    if (gDataService.added_event) {          
        window.calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',gDataService.added_event,false); // This adds this event to the calendar
        gDataService.added_event = null;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody would answer to this much sophisticated question.
You have some typos:
Missed closing with ";", "]"...
What's inside 'function calFactory'? What is '$broadcast'?
Why do you put '$' leading the JavaScript object? Is this meaning "private var"?
"if (!no_broadcast) ..." is not coding, but commenting.

Answer (score 0):

In "$scope.entry.$save( function(){",
Why entry doesn't have '$', but scope and save have it?